# What does a line count of a binary file mean?

Tags: file, binaryfiles, binary-data

```
:~$ wc -l bitmap.bmp
12931 bitmap.bmp
```

I would guess a binary file is like a stream, with no lines on it. So what does it mean when you talk about lines in a binary file?

(note: "wc -l" counts the lines in a file)

Alex Taylor pointed out below, as I suspected, that wc is counting the number of /n chars in the file.

So the question becomes: 
The '\n' characters that wc finds are there randomly when it translates binary to text or do actually exist in the binary file? As something as **b'\n'** (in Python)? And if yes, why would someone use the newline char in a binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the number of new line characters ('\n') in the data.

Looking at the [source code for MacOS' `wc`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-81/wc/wc.c), we see the following code:

```
if (doline) {
    while ((len = read(fd, buf, buf_size))) {
        if (len == -1) {
            warn("%s: read", file);
            (void)close(fd);
            return (1);
        }
        charct += len;
        for (p = buf; len--; ++p)
            if (*p == '\n')
                ++linect;
    }
```

It does a buffered read of the file, then loops through the data, incrementing a counter if it finds a '\n'.

The [GNU version of wc](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html) contains similar code:

```
/* Increase character and, if necessary, line counters */
#define COUNT(c)       \
      ccount++;        \
      if ((c) == '\n') \
        lcount++;
```

As to *why* a binary file has new line characters in it, they are just another value ([0x0A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) for the most common OS'). There is nothing special about the character unless the file is being interpreted as a text file. Likewise, tabs, numbers and all the other 'text' characters will also appear in a binary file. This is why using `cat` on a binary file can cause a terminal to beep wildly - it's trying to display the `BEL` character (0x07). Text is only text by convention.

Comment: Yeh, that's what i had guessed. But grep -o '\n' | wc -l didn't confirm it :)
But the '\n' characters it finds are there randomly when it translates binary to text or do actually exist in the binary file? As something as b'\n' ?

Comment: I won't give you correct answer yet, because the question is not how wc counts lines, it's what "lines" in a binary file mean, if anything.

Comment: @fullmooninu *But `grep -o '\n' | wc -l` didn't confirm it*  `grep` is a *text* processing utility that operates on *lines*, which are defined as being separated by `'\n'`.  Which part of a line matches the thing that separates individual lines?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can you explain better what do you mean? What I said was that you couldn't conclude anything from a failed experiment. But revisiting it:
:~$ grep -a '^' origin.bmp | wc -l
12932 


:~$ wc -l origin.bmp
12931 origin.bmp

But I'll say it again, my question is not how grep or wc work. It's what is the meaning of newlines in binary files, if any.